# Django Image Resizers

Tags: django, python-2.7

Currently I am working on a project that will have users upload a picture and they should scale down to a width of 210.

What is the best way to do this?

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
    from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill, Adjust

    class Photo(models.Model):
        photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        original = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
        main_page = ImageSpecField([ResizeToFill(210)], image_field='original', format='JPEG', options={'quality': 100})

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.photo_title
```

This does not generate the main_page image and as a result, photo.main_page does not get onto the template.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is only getting the resized photo to be displayed in a template, you'll be better off using [easy-thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails).

With it, your model can simply be:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    original = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
```

And in the template:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
<img src="{% thumbnail photo.original 210 crop quality=100 %}" alt="">
```

Comment: I have some problems, I have this: {% load thumbnail %}{% for photo in article.photos.all %} <p><img src="media/{% thumbnail photo.original 210 crop quality=100 %}"><p> {% endfor %}
            {% endif %} , it does not work.

Comment: Does it throw an error? Make sure you have Django [setup to serve media correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/).

Comment: no errors, just a frame without the pic, but un1t's app works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what works without any extras.

https://github.com/un1t/django-resized

As easy as:

```
from django_resized import ResizedImageField

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    original = ResizedImageField(max_width=210, upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
```

I am going to create a new model that will have both original and my pictures with various sizes.